# How to call a generic method with an anonymous type involving generics?

Tags: generics, scala, type-inference

I've got this code that works:

```
  def testTypeSpecialization: String = {
    class Foo[T]

    def add[T](obj: Foo[T]): Foo[T] =  obj

    def addInt[X <% Foo[Int]](obj: X): X = { 
      add(obj)
      obj
    }

    val foo = addInt(new Foo[Int] {
      def someMethod: String = "Hello world"
    })

    foo.someMethod
  }
```

But, I'd like to write it like this:

```
 def testTypeSpecialization: String = {
    class Foo[T]

    def add[X, T <% Foo[X](obj: T): T =  obj

    val foo = add(new Foo[Int] {
      def someMethod: String = "Hello world"
    })

    foo.someMethod
  }
```

This second one fails to compile:

**no implicit argument matching parameter type (Foo[Int]{ ... }) => Foo[Nothing] was found.**

Basically:

- I'd like to create a new anonymous
  class/instance on the fly (e.g. new
  Foo[Int] { ... } ), and pass it into
  an "add" method which will add it to
  a list, and then return it
- The key thing here is that the
  variable from "val foo = " I'd like
  its *type* to be the anonymous class,
  not Foo[Int], since it adds methods
  (someMethod in this example)

Any ideas?

I think the 2nd one fails because the type Int is being erased.  I can apparently 'hint' the compiler like this: (this works, but seems like a hack)

```
  def testTypeSpecialization = {
    class Foo[T]

    def add[X, T <% Foo[X]](dummy: X, obj: T): T =  obj

    val foo = add(2, new Foo[Int] {
      def someMethod: String = "Hello world"
    })

    foo.someMethod
  }
```

Comment: Well, thats good to hear :) hopefully it gets released soon!

Comment: Your error suggest a covariance problem (Though `X` *should* have never been deduced to `Nothing`) ... Tried `class Foo[+T]`?

Comment: That works, thx.. but breaks my other code. 

class Foo[+T] { var _val: Option[T] } fails to compile.

"covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type Option[T] of value _val"

Comment: Think this is just a bug in 2.7.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dario suggested making T covariant in Foo:

```
def testTypeSpecialization: String = {
    class Foo[+T] {
      var _val: Option[T]
    } 

    def add[X, T <% Foo[X](obj: T): T =  obj

    val foo = add(new Foo[Int] {
      def someMethod: String = "Hello world"
    })

    foo.someMethod
  }
```

But, with this adds too many restrictions to Foo it seems, e.g. I can't have a var member variable of type Option[T].

**covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type Option[T] of parameter of setter *val*=**